# highcharts find point with given x value

Tags: highcharts

I need to be able to find the points in series with a X value (time in milliseconds) falling in a given Year and Month, say Jan 1984, what is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a point by `x` value in this way:

```
var series = chart.series[0],
    index = series.xData.indexOf(1553779800000),
    point = series.points[index];
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h9qye01r/